# mikro-orm migration is not reflected in postgresql

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, migration, mikro-orm

this is User entity:

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryKey, Property } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { ObjectType, Field } from "type-graphql";

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryKey()
  id!: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property({ type: "date" })
  createdAt = new Date();

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property({ type: "date", onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt = new Date();

  @Field()
  @Property({ type: "text", unique: true })
  username!: string;

  @Field()
  @Property({ type: "text", unique: true })
  email!: string;

  @Property({ type: "text" })
  password!: string;
}
```

this is the migration script:

`"create:migration": "mikro-orm migration:create"`

I already had username and password column but when I tried to add "email" column, migration runs successfully but it does not reflected in database. This is the migration result:

```js
export class Migration20210608151159 extends Migration {

  async up(): Promise<void> {
    this.addSql('alter table "user" add column "email" text not null;');
    this.addSql('alter table "user" add constraint "user_email_unique" unique ("email");');
  }

}
```

I refresh table but do not see email column. When I send client request I get this error:

```
 error: insert into "user" as "e0" ("created_at", "email", "password", "updated_at", "username") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) returning * - column "email" of relation "user" does not exist
```

When I run `npx mikro-orm migration:up` this time I get this message:

```
"DriverException: alter table "user" add column "email" text not null; - column "email" of relation "user" already exists"
```

somehow migration is not modifying the database

Answer (score 1):

i found a way around it. we are probably following the same tutorial by ben awad.what i did was erase the whole User table from the postgres database. then i commented out the following command from index.ts.

`//await orm.getMigrator().up()`

later on i deleted all the previous migrations.

then i typed in terminal :

```
npx mikro-orm migration:create
```

then:

```
npx mikro-orm migration:validate
```

in order to make sure that the correct migration is about to be implemented

and then:

```
npx mikro-orm migration:up
```

In my opinion it seems like there is a problem with the migrator and the migration issues. i still haven't used the automatic migrator tool orm.getMigrator().up() but i may try it again in the future

Comment: I do not think that this is a valid command "npx mikro-orm migration:validate

Comment: i think it is valid, but you can omit it , it isn't necessary to use.

Answer (score 0):

You just created the migration, now you need to run it via `mikro-orm migration:up`.

```
npx mikro-orm migration:create   # Create new migration with current schema diff
npx mikro-orm migration:up       # Migrate up to the latest version
npx mikro-orm migration:down     # Migrate one step down
npx mikro-orm migration:list     # List all executed migrations
npx mikro-orm migration:pending  # List all pending migrations
```

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/migrations/#using-via-cli

Comment: I am getting this error : "DriverException: alter table "user" add column "email" text not null; - column "email" of relation "user" already exists" but when I sent request i get "relation does not exist" error. Also column does not get added to the db. I refresh the columns and db but column is not created

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the User entity is listed in `options.entities` inside `mikro-orm.config.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me watching Ben Awad's youtube video. I encounter this problem too. What I do was first searching in the discord form, and found that that the quickest way to resolve this is to drop/delete all tables in the database as well as migration files (both ts and .js file in dist folder [as mentioned here](http://npx%20mikro-orm%20migration:create) ).
Then run `npx mikro-orm migration:create`, `yarn dev` then you are good to go.